# PageUrl from Velocity

Tags: liferay, velocity, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I'm creating a theme on Liferay. I have a page for custom searches located in a special page in which the search portlet is contained.
I'm using the following syntax in velocity to get the URL of the page but I don't manage to obtain it:

## set($URL=$portalUtil.getLayoutFullURL($scopeGroupId,$portletIDsearch)

I do this because I don't want to use hard links.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
#set ($url = $themeDisplay.getURLCurrent())
```